# Removing "!" , "[" and "]" from Filenames

Tags: bash, unix

I'm trying to rename over 1700 videos for a emulator I'm putting together,

Some of the files can look like the following examples:

```
romfilename1!!! (Japan) [SLUS-01005].mp4
romfilename2 (USA) [SLUS-28605] (Disc 1).mp4
romfilename3 (USA) [SLUS-28605] (Disc 2).mp4
```

I'm trying to achieve the following results:

```
romfilename1.mp4
romfilename2 (Disc 1).mp4
romfilename3 (Disc 2).mp4
```

So far I've been able to remove (USA) & (Japan) by using:

```
for i in *.mp4
do
    mv "$i" "`echo $i | sed 's/ (USA)//'`"
done
```

So now I'm stuck on how I could go about removing the Exclamation Marks,
I've spent much time trying to search for an answer but havnt had much luck.
I am also stuck on how I got about removing these code thingys "[SLUS-28605]"
Mostly because of the brackets "[" and "]", the code inside is not important.
I've triend the following but the these particular characters mess things up.

```
for i in *.mp4
do
    mv "$i" "`echo $i | sed 's/!!//'`"
done
```

and...

```
for i in *.mp4
do
    mv "$i" "`echo $i | sed 's/[SLUS-28605]//'`"
done
```

and..

```
for i in *.mp4
do
    mv "$i" "`echo $i | sed -i 's/[]"[]//g'
done
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance, Nem

Comment: Try this : `sed 's/[!]*\|\[[^]]*\]\| *(Japan) *\| *(USA) *//g'`

Comment: @sat : please add it as an answer.

Comment: I tried using that command but it just seems to hang and do nothing :(

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `sed` for any of this.

```
shopt -s extglob
for i in *.mp4
do
    # Remove all !; the ! doesn't need to be escaped if history
    # expansion is disabled.
    new_i=${i//\!}

    # Remove the *first* parenthesized group (which contains the country)
    new_i=${new_i/ (+([!)]))}

    # Remove the bracketed group
    new_i=${new_i// \[*]}

    #mv "$i" "$new_i"

    echo "mv \"$i\" \"$new_i\""

done
```

You can remove the `echo` once you verify that the `mv` commands are correct.

Comment: i like the sed way better

Answer (score 1):

You can substitute multiple patterns in one line using **sed** and should escape special chars like spaces and square braces:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in *.mp4
do
   mv "$i" "$(echo $i | sed 's/!!!//;  s/\ (USA)\ //; s/\ (Japan)\ //; s/\[SLUS-[^][]*\]//')"
done
```

Comment: But how do I use this so it changes the filename?
It doesn't seem to do it on its own... Thanks

Comment: @NeMesiS Yes, it does change the filename. Note that the `sed` call is inside a command substitution `$()` which produces the second filename argument for the `mv` command.

Comment: @Kadir: I'd not use `.*` within a term that's supposed to remove braces/parentheses, it will do evil stuff when you have a filename like `[foo] bar [baz]`, removing `bar` alongside the bracketed expressions. I'd always use a character class like `[^][]*` in these cases.

Comment: Definitely probable for these kind of situations. Updated the answer. @cmaster

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rename` command for that. It supports regexes. So the command will looks like:

```
rename 's/[![]]//g' *
```

or

```
rename 's/[!]*\|\[[^]]*\]\| *(Japan) *\| *(USA) *//g' *
```

Though please double check man page of `rename` available in your system. E.g. deb-based and rpm-based distributives use different versions and regex will vary depending on your local rename version.

Regex should be adjusted to your complete requirement, as it is not really clear from the question.

It will also save from possible issues with special symbols in filename like `\n` and others.

Comment: Note that `rename` may be any one of a number of tools that tend to show up on Linux machines, and probably doesn't exist on non-Linux systems. So it's not portable, even between linuces.  Since the question didn't specify a particular platform (could be Linux, OSX, FreeBSD, Solaris, AIX, etc), it's best to make your answer portable.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ! :

```
for i in *.mp4
do
     name=`echo $i | sed 's/!//g'`
     mv "$i" "$name"
done
```

Eemove the [???] :

```
for i in *.mp4
do
     name=`echo $i | sed 's/\[[^][]*\]//g'`
     mv "$i" "$name"
done
```

Remove the (???) :

```
for i in *.mp4
do
     name=`echo $i | sed 's/([^)(]*)//g'`
     mv "$i" "$name"
done
```

If you want to remove all in once :

```
for i in *.mp4
do
     name=`echo $i | sed 's/!//g' | sed 's/([^)(]*)//g' | sed 's/\[[^][]*\]//g' `
     mv "$i" "$name"
done
```

Comment: As I already commented on Kadir's answer: it's not a good idea to use `.*` if you want to remove bracketed terms. Use a character class instead of the `.` operator, or be prepared that your regex does something you don't want.

Comment: @cmaster Do you mean something like [A-Za-z_0-9]* ?

Comment: More something like `[^][]*`. Of course, the more strict, the less likely you remove things you don't want. But also, the more strict, the more likely you don't want to remove things you want. So I would not say that one of `[^][]*` or `[A-Za-z_0-9]` is better than the other. The important part is to exclude the delimiters you are matching.